# CEP cannot detect multi event with same timestamp?

Tags: flink-cep

When I used CEP in Flink, I found a very interesting thing is there is only one event for a time.

For example, the DataStream that I used comes from a WindowStream, because it may update the occurrences of a same event, it will generates something like this: **(Event1, 2), (Event1, 3), (Event2, 1)**......

When i try to select the result of applying a pattern to this output DataStream, I found for that there is only **(Event1, 2), (Event2, 1)**....

Can somebody give me some clues why? It's the problem of design of pattern or Flink works like this way ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This is because:

> The CEP library **assumes correctness** of the watermark when working in
>   event time.

The details is in the [Handling Lateness in Event Time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/libs/cep.html#handling-timed-out-partial-patterns) / Fink doc